# How do I solve system of linear equations with 4 variables?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

We have system of linear equations $A\vec{x}=b$ :
$A=\begin{pmatrix}  2&  1&  -1& -1& 1& \\   1& -1&  1& 1& -2&  \\   3& 0& 0& 0&  -1&  \\   1&  -2&  5& 0& 0& \end{pmatrix}$ and
$\vec{b}=\begin{pmatrix}  a \\   b\\   c \\  d \end{pmatrix}$.

I know the value of $a=1, b=2, c=3 $ and $d=4$.

Now we know $b$ is a $4\times 1$ matrix, and A is a $4\times 5$.

So to get $4\times 1$ by multiplication of the two matrices, $x$ has to be a $5\times 1$ matrix, which is the variables.

So I think it will be:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}  2&  1&  -1& -1& 1& \\   1& -1&  1& 1& -2&  \\   3& 0& 0& 0&  -1&  \\   1&  -2&  5& 0& 0& \end{pmatrix}  \begin{pmatrix}  x\\   y\\   z \\  l \\ k\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}  a \\   b\\   c \\  d \end{pmatrix} $$

Is this good?

If yes than I get:

$2x+y-z-t+k=1$

$x-y+z+t-2k=2$

$3x-k=3$

$x-2y+5z=4$

Can someone tell me if I am on good way?  If yes, can someone help me to do this system of $4$ linear equations, because I'm making some mistakes in calculus always.

Comment: That is ok so far.

Comment: Are you familiar with Gaussian elimination?  It can structure what is process of essentially eliminating variables to get down to a parameterized family of solutions.  You might look up "augmented matrix" to get examples of how it applies in practice.

Comment: I have watched that but idk how to do it on 4x5

Comment: You can keep $x,y,z,t$ in one side and move $k$ to the RHS, then you would have $4\times 4$ matrix that you are familiar with.

Comment: Can you do it please?